# Tomcat 7 console and/or tray icon not showing up when running as a windows service

Tags: windows, tomcat

I have installed Tomcat7 as a service(service.bat). It starts and works fine as a service, but I don't see a console that usually comes up when you manually start the server using Tomcat7.exe or startup.bat.

Btw, I'm on windows 7 and I have tried a few things from here - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

I can put the 'Tomcat7w monitor application' to the tray using - tomcat7w //MS//tomcat7w

But I need a console and and/or a tray icon for the Tomcat7 service itself.

Answer (score 15):

The solution is that go to the tomcat/bin folder in a command prompt window then try something like that: tomcat8w //MS//Tomcat8

And that's it, the monitor service appear.

Comment: What does "//MS" refer to?

Comment: MS = Monitor Service. This suggested solution did not work for me (Tomcat7/Windows7), BTW - still looking for a solution.

Comment: it has worked fine, just need to replace //MS//Tomcat8 by your Tomcat Service name, example //MS//MyTomcatService. So previously by retrieving correct name into services listing (run command >> "services.msc")

Answer (score 0):

I found this on apache.org http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html at the bottom of the page is info on the console.

In linux one could simply do a tail -f on a text file and see te log entries come in so i googled for a replacement on windows [this is it](http://code.google.com/p/snaketail-net/) I hope it is of use.

Comment: I have tried - C:\> tomcat7 //TS//Tomcat7  but this tries to start the service with the console even if the service is already running.

Comment: That will delete the service. And I don't think I can start it again before installing it as a service again, but this this is not what I want.

Comment: I understand my bad didn't pay attention.

Comment: I tried installing tomcat via service.bat but it wont start a console while tomcat service is installing and working after starting

Comment: Yeah exactly my problem. The [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Command_line_arguments) say that a console is default when running as a service.

Comment: On [this site](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat6_HowTo.html) I found this remark. A flip side of running Tomcat as a service is you need to read the error messages from $CATALINA_HOME\logs instead of the Tomcat console. So I think it is also a down side for tomcat7 but did not find confirmation yet.

Comment: Even I found something like that [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) But i don't understand this part - "Note that when choosing to run Tomcat at the end of installation, the tray icon will be used even if Tomcat was installed as a service."

Comment: They are talking about the windows installer the exe file not a extracted archive. it took me a little while to figure it out.

Comment: Oh ok. Makes sense. Btw, thanks for SnakeTail. Should do the job for now.