# Tomcat 8 System Tray Icon

Tags: windows, tomcat, tomcat8

I've been trying to get the Tomcat8 system tray icon to appear on a Windows Server 2012 box, but I'm running into an issue. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312043/4925189) to put the Tomcat 8 icon in the system try. So, I ran the following command

```
C:\..\bin>tomcat8w //MS//Tomcat8
```

The icon shows up in the system tray, as expected, but when I reboot my machine the icon is no longer there, and I must run the same command in order for it to appear again. Is there anything I can do to ensure that the icon remains persistently?

Comment: Same problem here. Some additional information:

Same problem under Windows 10. Affects Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8. Executing Tomcat Monitor in Windows Start menu brings back the icon, too (but it disappears after reboot). No problems under Windows 7 (same pc, I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10).

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions for this.
What worked for me is the following:
Create a .bat to run at windows log on that opens the tomcat icon tray.
To do so, just use what you posted before:
Open a notepad and type the following:

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\Tomcat7w.exe" //MS//Tomcat7

Go to file --> Save as...
Select the location C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
in "Filename:" type, TomcatMonitor.bat
in "Save as type" select, All Files (*.*)

That's it. Next time your computer log on it will run the script to open the Tomcat monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 8: If you installed in the default location, type +R, then enter

```sh
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin\Tomcat8w.exe" //MS//
```

and click OK. This will install the feather icon into the system tray (regardless of whether you had it before or not).